# How to set volume for dokku-persistent-storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, docker, digital-ocean

I am trying to use [dokku-persistent-storage](https://github.com/dyson/dokku-persistent-storage) so my uploads for my rails app stay on the server, but I don't quite understand how to build the path since I am new to [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku) and [Docker](https://www.docker.io/).
(I am running this on an Ubuntu droplet on Digital Ocean)

---

**I'm not sure if it should be something like this:**

```
[SERVER IP ADDRESS]/home/dokku/myapp/public_folder
```

or

```
/home/dokku/myapp/public_folder
```

or if i'm way off and it should be something completely different.

---

**This is what the github section says about it:**

In your applications folder (/home/dokku/app_name) create a file called PERSISTENT_STORAGE.

Inside this file list one volume-map/volume per line to mount. For example:

```
/host/path:/container/path
/another/container/path
```

The above example will result in the following arguments being passed to docker during deploy and docker run:

```
-v /host/path:/container/path -v /another/container/path
```

Move information on docker volumes can be found here: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_volumes/

Comment: The examples you cite are for "data volumes". These volumes are physically under `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir`, for a standard install. To know which folder is the root for your running container, you can try `docker inspect <container id> | less`, and search for the `Volume` lines. You will find the exact path there. Is that helpful? If so, I can answer the question properly.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to choose the exact path on the Docker host, the syntax with host mounts is perhaps what you need. Then, the path on the host and the containers are "free"---just be sure they exist. Note the container path is relative to the container root. So `/container/path` is rooted in the container, even though is starts with `/`.

Comment: Mistake: Replace `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir` for `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.

Comment: Apparently the same situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605774/how-to-properly-configure-persistent-volumes-on-dokku-with-rails

Answer (score 0):

I am not into Ruby or dokku, but if I understood correctly, you want your docker to have a persistent storage on the host machine.

PERSISTENT_STORAGE file, as to the documentation that you've quoted, contains mappings from host file-system directories to your container file-system directories (translated to -v arguments of the CLI).

Therefore, you should map the directory of your uploads in the container, to the desired directory on the host.

For example, if your app's uploads are saved to this dir (inside the docker container):

```
/home/dokku/myapp/public_folder
```

and you'd like them to be kept in your host at:

```
/home/some/dir
```

then, as I understand, the content of PERSISTENT_STORAGE file should be:

```
/home/some/dir:/home/dokku/myapp/public_folder
```

I hope I got you right.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dokku's `storage:mount` option.

1. You'll need to SSH into your dokku host:
   `ssh dokku@host`
2. Run the following command to link the storage directory for that app to the `app/public/uploads` folder, for example:

   `storage:mount <app> /var/lib/dokku/data/storage:/app/public/uploads`

The Dokku docs cover this well at: at http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/advanced-usage/persistent-storage/